# How can I find a comment with specified text string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, robobrowser

I'm using robobrowser to parse some html content. I has a BeautifulSoup inside. How can I find a comment with specified string inside

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<!-- some commented code here!!!<div><ul><li><div id='ANY_ID'>TEXT_1</div></li>
<li><div>other text</div></li></ul></div>-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In fact I need to get TEXT_1 if I know ANY_ID
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `text` argument and check the type to be `Comment`. Then, load the contents with `BeautifulSoup` again and find the desired element by `id`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Comment

data = """
<html>
<body>
<div>
<!-- some commented code here!!!<div><ul><li><div id='ANY_ID'>TEXT_1</div></li>
<li><div>other text</div></li></ul></div>-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
comment = soup.find(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment) and "ANY_ID" in text)

soup_comment = BeautifulSoup(comment, "html.parser")
text = soup_comment.find("div", id="ANY_ID").get_text()
print(text)
```

Prints `TEXT_1`.